# Helper that hold methods for evaluate and calculate data

Tags: c#, floating-point

I would like some advice to shorten down this snippet, give it more efficient flow and look. Review should focus on keeping it as a compact single method (except the two public props). The `DataType` and `MeasureStatus` is an `enum`. Readability is of course more important than compactness.

```
....
/// <summary>
/// Helper that hold methods for evaluate and calculate data 
/// that will be serialized/deserialized in Serializer/SerializerBase.
/// Please don't put serializing routines in here and also understand 
/// that some decisions here are based on protocol specifikations.
/// </summary>
....
public Unit MeasureType { get; set; }
public ModeType Aggregate { get; set; }
.....

public Tuple<DataType, byte> EvaluateDataType(double value, MeasureStatus? status = null)
{
    int quantityOfDecimals = 0;
    DataType dataType = DataType.MISSING_LONG;
    byte nibbled = 0;
    bool statusIsMissing = false;

    if (status != null)
        if (status == MeasureStatus.Missing)
            statusIsMissing = true;

    quantityOfDecimals = 
      (this.MeasureType == Unit.kWh || this.MeasureType == Unit.ºC) ? 1 : 2;

    // Qty decimals affect limit size  of 'value'
    if (quantityOfDecimals == 1)
    {
        if (value < 3276 && value > -3276)
            if (!statusIsMissing)
                dataType = DataType.SHORT_1DEC;
            else
                dataType = DataType.MISSING_SHORT;
        else
            if (!statusIsMissing)
                dataType = DataType.LONG_1DEC;
            else
                dataType = DataType.MISSING_LONG;
    }

    // Qty decimals affect limit size  of 'value'
    if (quantityOfDecimals == 2)
    {
        if (value < 327 && value > -327)
            if (!statusIsMissing)
                dataType = DataType.SHORT_2DEC;
            else
                dataType = DataType.MISSING_SHORT;
        else
            if (!statusIsMissing)
                dataType = DataType.LONG_2DEC;
            else
                dataType = DataType.MISSING_LONG;
    }

    nibbled = (byte)(Aggregate | dataType);
    return new Tuple<DataType, byte>(dataType, nibbled);
}
```

Comment: If there are design decisions that are driving this, then they need to be referenced in comments, probably more than just a 'look here for why' (unless you have a good referencing system with tool...).  Magic numbers are still bad, perhaps _especially_ if specified externally - you only want to have to change **ONE** value if the specification changes, not look for a million hard-coded values (and in your case, they aren't written as the same value anyways!).  And never rely on a developer reading documentation before looking at isolated code...

Comment: Thank's. I think this fell outside of the scoop of question. Also we came to goal of the question already,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some (potentially bizarre to me) things going on here.  A slightly larger view of the system may be helpful in further refining this method.  In any case, here's how I'd restructure this.  I've also included notes about some things I found odd...

```
public Tuple<DataType, byte> EvaluateDataType(double value, MeasureStatus? status = null) 
{ 

    // As much as possible, initialize a local variable to the proper value
    // when you declare it (as if it had Java's *final* attatched).
    // This isn't always possible, of course
    DataType dataType;
    // Really, these are the only two datatypes that use 1 decimal place?
    int decimalPlaces = (MeasureType == Unit.kWh || MeasureType == Unit.ºC) ? 1 : 2;
    // Structure your code so that it's values and executions give the -reasons-
    // or the -why-.  The code itself says -what- is happening, but it's usually -why-
    // that's actually important.  
    // Among other things, this means you should (usually) avoid magic numbers. 
    bool valueOutOfRange = Math.Abs(value) >= (Int16.MaxValue / (10 * decimalPlaces)); 

    // status == null is considered -present-?
    if (status != null && status == MeasureStatus.Missing) 
    {
    // Note, never leave off brackets - {} - you run a nasty risk of
    // someone writing indented code that isn't actually part of the block.   
    // Also, as much as possible, test for -affirmative- results, not negative ones.
    // Although, multiple negatives should still be avoided.         
        if (valueOutOfRange) 
        {
            dataType = DataType.MISSING_LONG;
        } 
        else
        {
            dataType = DataType.MISSING_SHORT;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (valueOutOfRange) 
        {
            if (decimalPlaces == 1) 
            {
                dataType = DataType.LONG_1DEC;
            }
            else
            {
                dataType = DataType.LONG_2DEC;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (decimalPlaces == 1)
            {
                dataType = DataType.SHORT_1DEC;
            }
            else 
            }
                dataType = DataType.SHORT_2DEC;
            }
        }
    }

    // Are you sure you don't mean "byte nibbled = (byte) (Aggregate & dataType);"?
    // I'm assuming you're attempting to mask Aggregate for the cast, and that 
    // you haven't done anything -too- out there in the operator override.
    byte nibbled = (byte) (Aggregate | dataType);
    return new Tuple<DataType, byte>(dataType, nibbled);
}
```

Although, I'm a little suspicious of anything that's moving some sort of `DataType` around like this (especially because you're only storing a `byte`).  Normally it's best to prefer some sort of implemented generic, so you can get *compile time* checking of your datatypes.  Nothing like mismatches at runtime to crash your probe into Mars (granted, that was a mismatch in the measure type, which you're attempting to cover here.  However, you still need to deal with value mis-matches...).

Comment: ermm "never leave off brackets".  I think your missing a bracket after the else statement just after this comment :)  Otherwise good feedback.  To some degree I think your use of spacing helps the readability more than the changes.

Comment: @dreza - Thanks.  This is another reason why - your compile can catch that you've put something in the wrong place.  I don't have a C# compiler here.

Comment: Updated! I hope the edits are clear enough, at last.

Comment: One super-minor-pity comment, `decimalPlaces` = number of `,`?

Comment: @Jonas - `decimalPlaces` is equivalent to your `quantityOfDecimals`, which is a somewhat counter-intuitive name.  Usually, 'decimal places' is used to refer to how many `places` (digits) are present to the _right_ of the decimal-point - tenths, hundreths, thousandths, and so on.

Comment: @X-Zero There can be some funny translations between languages. I got a hard lesson ones, regarding the word "decimalPlaces" which refer to `0.000,000,000,000,009` = 4 if we talk i.e. number formatting. In this case though, the code says that at isn't the kind of use. `3.444` <-- three decimals. Your probably right, just the word Decimals would fit perfectly!

Comment: @jonas - (American) english speakers would most likely expect a variable named `quantityOfDecimals` or similar to be an array of decimals, each (probably) different.  The wikipedia page on [arithmetic precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_precision) details how most would expect it to be used.